How to connect to a HyperV VM (Kali guest) using Remote desktop? (Win10 host)
I just trying to access without starting a HyperV instance but a RPD conection. I already tried a lot of ways published here (Superuser) but, for instance: In this Tutorial 1 I've followed the steps but didn't work, using ports 3390 or 3389, even tried using an internal instead an external connection (don't useful: I need Internet access from VM). Already installed xrdp on Kali, the service has been started.
Don't know what I have to do. Help, please 
